# How to enumerate number when I press a key in the Keyboard module?

Tags: python, keyboard

How to enumerate number when I press a key in the Keyboard module ?

But no all the number at once

For example if I have the numbers 1,2,3,4,5

when I press 'r' once, the number 1 is displayed then If I press R a second time it's 2 that is displayed and then 3 etc

Until it reaches 5 the next time we press the key we'll got 1 again.

Idk if I'm clear but when I make the loop it display all of them at once.

**EDIT 1 :**

The first time I tested the code below the following error came out:

(Yes I had imported threading but I need it for a different script written on the same file)

```
rException in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 106, in start_reading
    self.event_queue.put(device.read_event())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 83, in read_event
    data = self.input_file.read(struct.calcsize(event_bin_format))
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device
```

Comment: For the reset to 1 I was thinking about the % modulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable `count` that holds the amount of clicks you have made. To reset it to 1, you can use an `if` statement like so:

```
if count > 5:
    count = 1
```

Alternatively, you can use a **modulo** `%` operator like you mentioned:

```
count = count % 5
```

EDIT: to increment count variable when key is pressed, use a loop. Full code:

```py
count = 0
while True:
    # check if 'r' is pressed
    if keybord.is_pressed('r'):
        # increment count variable
        count += 1
        # reset it to 1 if it is greater than 5
        # alternatively use modulo operator
        if count > 5:
            count = 1
```

EDIT 2: The reason why it keeps printing out lots of numbers is because it prints it out for every iteration that the key is pressed, instead of it being called just once. The following code checks if the key was previously pressed and executes the code if it hasn't:

```py
import keyboard
count = 0
has_clicked = False
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        if has_clicked == False:
            count += 1
            if count > 5:
                count = 1
            has_clicked = True
            print(count)
    else:
            has_clicked = False
```

Comment: Sometimes the error above comes back and sometimes it's a lot of numbers that are displayed at once instead of one at a time when you press 'r

 the numbers are displayed all at once instead of displaying one number per key pressed and reset when you press 'r'  > 5 times (basically when you exceed the limit)

Comment: I made a new edit above and see if it works. Basically, the previous code detects every iteration of the loop where the key is pressed. The other error you're getting about OSerror is likely a different problem in your code.